# sort files by ascii order

Tags: sorting, ascii, dirent.h

I'm trying to code a simple function to sort the content of a directory. The Thing is, it comes out in alphabetical order, regardless of uppercase or lowercase. I'd like to sort this content in ASCII order.

example: I got 4 files, named Art, boat, Cat and donkey. My actual code sort them in this order, while i'd like to get Art, Cat, boat and donkey.

```
void    list_dir(char *str){
DIR *rep = NULL;
struct dirent* read_file = NULL;

rep = opendir(str);
if (!rep)
{
    ft_putstr("ft_ls: ");
    perror(str);
    ft_putchar('\n');
}
while((read_file = readdir(rep)) != NULL)
{
    if (read_file->d_name[0] != '.')
    {
        ft_putstr(read_file->d_name);
        ft_putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the sorting happening? It looks like you are just reading a directory and printing it as-is. Also, you need an `else` before the `while`

Comment: I don't knoz, thing is, it seems to be automatic, I just wrote this and it turned out to sort whatever it read

Comment: That's because whatever OS you are on probably sorts its directory contents. You need to read them in and sort them, only then print them.

Comment: Take a look at `qsort` in `stdlib.h`. That should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

[readdir(3)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man3/readdir) does not normally sort at all, it lists the entries in directory order. If the list is sorted, either the files were created sorted, or the OS sorts them.

In order to sort the output yourself, put the list of names into an array then sort it e.g. with [qsort(3)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man3/qsort) and [strcmp(3)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man3/strcmp).

Alternatively, just pipe the output through [sort(1)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/sort). Do make sure that the `LC_COLLATION` environment variable is set proper. For example, run `./yourprogram | (unset LC_ALL; LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=C sort)`.

Answer (score 0):

By calling **scandir** with user defined filter & comparator is a simple solution imho. Here is the code:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int my_dir_filter(const struct dirent* dir);
static int my_dir_comparator(const struct dirent**, const struct dirent**);

int main(int argc, char* const* argv) {
    struct dirent** ent_list_ = NULL;
    int r = scandir(".", &ent_list_, my_dir_filter, my_dir_comparator);
    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
        printf("No. %-3d [%s]\n", i + 1, ent_list_[i]->d_name);
    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
        free(ent_list_[i]);
    free(ent_list_);
    return r < 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

int my_dir_filter(const struct dirent* dir) {
    return (dir->d_type == DT_REG) ? 1 : 0;
}

int my_dir_comparator(const struct dirent** lhs, const struct dirent** rhs) {
    return strcasecmp((*lhs)->d_name, (*rhs)->d_name);
}
```

And test result:

```
$ ls|LANG=C sort   ## in ASCII order
Art
Cat
boat
donkey
$ ../a.out         ## in my_dir_comparator order
No. 1   [Art]
No. 2   [boat]
No. 3   [Cat]
No. 4   [donkey]
```